# How to clear http basic Authorization credentials saved in the browser

Tags: javascript, angular, cross-browser, http-authentication

In an angular application, I send an XHR login request to a stateless rest server with http auth header:

```
http
          .get(`${site.url}/login`, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${username}:${password}`)}`,
            },
            withCredentials: true,
          })
```

Anytime I request the same server then, I don't need to send the credentials again: they are saved automatically by the browser. This is nice, this way I don't have to save the credentials on the browser (the server is stateless, so there is no session nor token available).

However this introduces a security issue: when the user logouts (this is a simple boolean stored in the browser), his browser is still able to connect to the server: in case of XSS someone could connect again.

Is there any way, from Javascript, to clear these credentials? I saw some hacks (request the server with bad credentials...) but I am looking for a consistent & safe way.

Answer (score -1):

Headers are immutable - they can't be changed. However you can use a technology called JWT (JSON Web Token).[Here a link for **JWT**'s website.](https://jwt.io/)